# django: unable to login after successful registration

Tags: django

login reporting wrong username or password, after a new user is registered successfully. I am sure the there is no typo! below is my code and I guess the problem is to do with the hash code related to the password setup?

```
@csrf_exempt
def api_register(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    username = data['username']
    password_1 = data['password_1']
    password_2 = data['password_2']

    # 1，check if two pw is same
    if password_1 != password_2:
        return JsonResponse({"code": 0, "msg": "pw not consistant"})

    else:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(password_1.encode())
        password_m = m.hexdigest()

        # 2 check if username exists

        users = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if users:
            return JsonResponse({"error": "username already exists"})
        else:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username = username, password = password_m)
                user.set_password(password_m)
                user.save()
                user.is_active = True
                user.success = True
                ret_data = {"username": user.username, 'uid': user.id, 'password': user.password}
                token = TimestampSigner(sep='.').sign_object(ret_data)
                ret_data['token'] = token
                ret = {"code": 1, "msg": ret_data}
            except Exception as e:
                print('--create user error is %s' % e)
                return JsonResponse({"error": "username already exists"})
            return JsonResponse(ret)
```

below is login function

```
@csrf_exempt
def api_login(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    user = authenticate(**data) #same as authenticate(username=data['username'],password=data['password']

    if user:
        ret_data = {"username":user.username,'uid':user.id}
        token = TimestampSigner(sep='.').sign_object(ret_data)
        ret_data['token'] = token
        ret = {"code":1,"msg":ret_data}
        print("ret ", ret)
    else:
        ret = {"code":0,"msg":"username or password wrong!" }
    return JsonResponse(ret)
```

Comment: Why are you hashing the password when you register?

Answer (score 0):

Django's `.set_password` hashes the password itself, so you should not to that manually. By doing this, the authentication will of course no longer work, since the entered password is not the same as the MD5-hashing. Furthermore MD5 is not considered a "safe" hasher.

```
@csrf_exempt
def api_register(request):
    data = request.json()
    username = data['username']
    password_1 = data['password_1']
    password_2 = data['password_2']

    # 1 check if two pw is same
    if password_1 != password_2:
        return JsonResponse({'code': 0, 'msg': 'pw not consistant'})

    # 2 check if username exists
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'username already exists'})
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=username, password=password1, is_active=True, success=True
    )
    ret_data = {'username': user.username, 'uid': user.id, 'password': password1}
    token = TimestampSigner(sep='.').sign_object(ret_data)
    ret_data['token'] = token
    return JsonResponse({'code': 1, 'msg': ret_data})
```

Comment: How does one make the hash algorithm safer in this instance? I think it's important to stress security best practices even if it's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @Swift: Django already hashes the password, by default with pbkdf2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: Are there other viable options?

Comment: @Swift: you can configure another hasher in the settings, and specify any function, so plug in Keccak for example.

Comment: I've never heard of Keccak, so I'll surely take a look, thank you :)